# Processing the same data in performance testing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I will do a performance test. The same data cannot be added more than once on the page where I add data. In this case, when I run the performance test with 50 users, the data runs while performing parallel processing and an error is received in the test. What can be done to prevent this situation?

I shouldn't get errors when I perform the same requests with multiple users

Comment: You should focus on the server you are running more. The question is not very clear about which error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've recorded some scenario and trying to replay it with 50 users and who know how many iterations - it will be using the same (recorded) request all the time.

In case if the system under test doesn't allow duplicate data to be created you need to:

1. Either [parameterize the test data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization) using external data sources (CSV files, relational databases, etc.) so each virtual user would use different data on each iteration
2. Or use i.e. [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which can be used for generating unique data, for example:

   - [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) returns current timestamp
   - [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) returns the number of current thread (virtual user)
   - [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) returns GUID-like structure
   - [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) - can execute arbitrary [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code, for example you can get the current iteration number as `${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)}`